# Marriage certificate without previous marriage state

Tags: europe, paperwork, weddings

Me and my girlfriend, we want to marry. Though we've got one problem: We are looking for a country to travel in Europe, where we can get marriage certificate that doesn't include previous marital status in it. We already have all documents, that allow us to get married and we're ready to translate it to any language needed.

So, briefly, we need to find a country in Europe, where we can get married and receive a marriage certificate, where it would't be written that marital status before marriage was single, divorced, widowed, etc.

Thanks in advance for all possible tips and suggestions.

Comment: and why would you want that, except in order to commit fraud somewhere or some other illegal activity?

Comment: Come to Nevada...

Comment: There is no fraud, when we will be getting married, we will provide all documents, including our current marital status, of course. There are a lot of countries, that don't include marital status in their marriage certificates and it doesn't mean, that every married couple there are potential fraudsters, if it could be used illegally, wouldn't this status be written in  certificates of all developed countries?
Karlson, thanks for invitation, but it's quite far away from us :).

Comment: Would the country you live in recognize that marriage certificate directly or is it required that you get the marriage approved (or certified or similar) when you return? And would that process require that you hand over the foreign marriage certificate in exchange for a certificate with unwanted information? You might want to check that you're not wasting a lot of money for no benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, in France (“copie d'acte de mariage” or “extrait d'acte de mariage”) or Germany (“Eheurkunde”), marriage certificates do not mention the previous status of the spouses. Obviously if you were to divorce from this marriage then this divorce would be mentioned in the register as well. You can't just drop in and marry, however. In France, for example, you must generally be a resident of the municipality where you want to marry, announce the marriage in advance and also provide some documents from your embassy if you're a foreign national.